# Remove duplicate String(Ignore Case) from list in angular 8 using lodash

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I have a list of String with duplicate entries , So i want to remove them irrespective of Case

```
let duplicates = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'hello'];
let uniques = _.methodName(duplicates);

// output should be
['hello','Hi'] OR ['Hello','Hi']
```

Comment: Does this have to be lodash? Here's a vanilla js question: [javascript unique string array case insensitive but keep one case sensitive result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.uniqWith()` with a callback as following:

```js
let duplicates = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'hello'];

let uniques = _.uniqWith(duplicates, (a,b) => a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase())

console.log(uniques);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that avoids the need for a dependancy like lodash would be the following "vanilla js" approach:

```js
let duplicates = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'hello'];

/* Pluck the values of the object mapping to an array */
let uniques = Object.values(
  /* "Reduce" input array to an object mapping */
  duplicates.reduce((obj, str) =>     
  /* Insert str value into obj mapping with lower case key */
  ({ ...obj, [str.toLowerCase()] : str }), {})
);

console.log(uniques)
```

Here an object mapping case insenstive keys to case sensitive values is built via [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). This mapping ensures that unique values are obtained irrespective of case. The [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method is then used to transform that mapping to the required `uniques` array.

#### Update

If [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is not available in your browser, you can use the following solution:

```js
let duplicates = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'hello'];

let mapping = duplicates.reduce((obj, str) => 
  ({ ...obj, [str.toLowerCase()] : str }), {})
let uniques = Object.keys(mapping).map(k => mapping[k])

console.log(uniques)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, But i m getting some error "Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'."

Comment: @AnkeshPandey you're welcome, just updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: Again Thanks, Now its working.But is it an efficient way by looping all the elements of the list. Is there any other approach for the same?

Comment: Yep, just updated again to use mapping - in terms of efficiency, the for..in loop method will be the fastest alternate method. With the small amount of data your likely detailing with though, the updated "map" based method is probably fine as well, and quite a bit cleaner, code wise. Hope that's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple with **`_.uniq`** and **`_.map`**

**Here is an exmaple:**

```
let uniqueData = _.uniq(_.map(duplicates, (d) => d.toLowerCase()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) with [`_.toLower()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toLower) as iteratee:

```js
const duplicates = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'hello'];

const result = _.uniqBy(duplicates, _.toLower);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use uniqBy methods

```
_.uniqBy(data, function (e) {
  return e.id;
});
```